# From site percolation to bond percolation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, percolation

Is it right saying that the site percolation of a square lattice is equivalent to the bond percolation of it's line graph, a chessboard lattice? There is a similar question about whether that is the case with all graphs but there seems to be no good answer so perhaps simplified to just a square lattice and its line graph has a simpler proof/disprove.

Comment: I think it should be "Site percolation on the line graph of the square lattice is equivalent to bond percolation on the square lattice". At least, that is my conclusion when drawing the graphs.